# How to add a user in a different Active Directory Domain in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, cross-domain

So my goal is to be able to add a user from one Active Directory Domain to another group in a separate Active Directory Domain.

I'd like to do this in C#.  I know there is a System.DirectoryServices namespace with classes to communicate with AD, but I can't find any information on adding users across domains.

In the environment there are two domain controllers with the same parent forest.  There is a transient trust between the 2 domains, let's call them domains A and B.

I'm able to add a user from B to a Domain Local or Universal group inside of domain A with the Active Directory tool.

Does anyone know how I can do this programmatically using C#?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me when I wrote code to do this a couple years back:

1. Get a DirectoryEntry for the group to which you want to add a member.
2. Call Invoke on the group DirectoryEntry passing arguments "Add" as the method name and the [ADsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746384(VS.85).aspx) of the member in an array.

Some sample code off the top of my head:

```
DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://CN=foo,DC=domainA");
string memberADsPath = @"LDAP://CN=bar,DC=domainB";
group.Invoke("Add", new Object[] {memberADsPath});
```

Comment: This does not work for me, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984105/add-member-to-ad-group-from-a-trusted-domain. Maybe if the two domains are managed on the same DCs (if that's possible at all), but my domains are really separate, just trusted. I need to work out a solution with ForeighSecurityPrincipal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DirectoryEntry object to the Group.  Then you add the DN off the user you want to add to the group to the member attribute on the group.  For example:

```
DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://child.domain.com/cn=group,ou=sample,dc=child,dc=domain,dc=com");

string userDN = "cn=user,ou=sample,dc=domain,dc=com";

group.Properties["member"].Add(userDN);
group.CommitChanges();
```

Probably your having issues getting bound to the group DirectoryEntry.  Make sure you can read attributes off that DE before you try adding a group to make sure your successfully binding.