# C# Active Directory: Add user to group in another domain

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I created a Windows Form application to create an active directory user account in domain1 and aims to add it to the groups which are inside domain2. Here is the code I used:

```
PrincipalContext pc1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain1.company.com", "DC=domain1,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(pc1, "username", "password", true);
up.Save();

PrincipalContext pc2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain2.company.com", "DC=domain2,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc2, "groupname");
gp.Members.Add(up);
gp.Save();
```

When I debug it in Visual Studio, the newly created user can be added to the group successfully. However, After I published and run it again, it returns error `"There is no such object on the server".`

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: And by publishing you exactly mean?

Comment: I just click "Build" and "Publish" in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on the same requirement, not so exactly, and we were required to process newly created user.

*So, I tried two solutions -*

### Solution 1

Make thread to sleep for few milliseconds such as-

```
PrincipalContext pc1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain1.company.com", "DC=domain1,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(pc1, "username", "password", true);
up.Save();

Thread.Sleep (500);

PrincipalContext pc2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain2.company.com", "DC=domain2,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc2, "groupname");
gp.Members.Add(up);
gp.Save();
```

This way, the AD is able to sync the user details in the entire domain and domain controller. And the user is found in next steps.

### Solution 2

By default, the `DirectoryEntry` object holds information about a user in the cache for performance reason. It doesn't reflect changes automatically.

So, we need to refresh the related cache by-

```
PrincipalContext pc1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain1.company.com", "DC=domain1,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(pc1, "username", "password", true);
up.Save();

 // Refresh cache so that we get updated user object
 var de = (DirectoryEntry)up.GetUnderlyingObject();
 de.RefreshCache();

PrincipalContext pc2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain2.company.com", "DC=domain2,DC=company,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc2, "groupname");
gp.Members.Add(up);
gp.Save();
```

*I recommend using Solution 2 if it works out fine.*

Comment: I tried to create another UserPrincipal object by FindByIdentify() method, but it also throws the same error.

Comment: Did you check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984105/add-member-to-ad-group-from-a-trusted-domain?