# .Net 4.5.2 - IsMemberOf() requires DNS configuration?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to add user as member of group in trusted domain.

I have been following the code sampel from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984105/add-member-to-ad-group-from-a-trusted-domain)

The `IsMemberOf()` fails with error:
`Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)`

Looking for a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608971/net-4-5-bug-in-userprincipal-findbyidentity-system-directoryservices-accountma), they say that it is a regression introduced in .Net 4.5 and was solved in 4.5.1
I have 4.5.2 installed.

If I configure the DNS, it works !!

The trouble I am having is the windows machine from where the code is executed can't have the DNS configured to the same AD server. It's a test machine and each time different AD servers will be used.

Comment: ActiveDirectory is heavily based on DNS ... it is like the air to breath - you cannot live without

Comment: The DNS for Active Directory is just fine. The testbed from where I am executing the test code `IsMemberOf()` is complaining for DNS

Comment: Yes, and DNS needs to be properly setup at server **and** client to work

Comment: If you look at that 'solution' link I posted, they removed the client side DNS restricition in 4.5.1 form FindByIdentity() call. Might be IsMemberOf() is still broken